# How do I make an HTML border change color with the mouseover event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make some images on my website be more interactive. I want to have it where the bottom border changes color when the mouse moves over it. This is what I currently have:

```js
function bigImg(x) {
    x.border-bottom-color = "#00ff00";
}

function normalImg(x) {
x.border-bottom-color = "black";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your object `x` has a `style` attribute, which itself has keys for all css `keywords` you know. You can access them by `x.style['border-bottom-color']`. See also the answer of @Osama.

Comment: why JavaScript ? you can use css hover

Comment: works like @Osama wrote, but realy, the better way is to use css for a hover effect. if you only use js you have to write a onMouseLeave event too.

Comment: I got it working with CSS. I guess I should get to learn CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.borderBottomColor= "#00ff00";
}

function normalImg(x) {
x.style.borderBottomColor= "black";
}
```

To use style within javascript use .style after your element then start the CSS property with small letter word then each word with capital letter

Comment: Thank you for this note and sorry , I am using my iPhone now so these errors happened

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  div.mouseOverUnderline {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
  div.mouseOverUnderline:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red
  }
</style>
<div class="mouseOverUnderline">here is my mouseover effect<div>
```

here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5swwu091/

Answer (score 0):

if you really need to JavaScript then already you have solution on other answer. But there is a **alternative solution using css**.
Check the below css you can use this class for which one is normal or which one img is big.

```css
img.bigImg:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #00ff00;
}
img.normalImg:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <img class="bigImg" src="http://aven-sys.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/demo.jpg">
<br><br>
 <img class="normalImg" src="http://aven-sys.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/demo.jpg">
```